# VR : Player rotated the wrong way in store GUI

Tags: google-vr

We are in great need of assistance:

When we move the player from our scene into the VR: Google Store GUI (Desert scene)
No matter how we rotate or reset the position of the player before the desert loads, the message box (with confirm button) ALWAYS spawn behind the player.

This forces the player to always rotate around 180 to interact with the confirm button.

We are out of ideas...

Greatful for any help!

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please read the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
In particular, you haven't included any information that would help others reproduce your problem. 
You could also do well to describe what troubleshooting you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!